# Como agrego clases con herencia al addClass

Tags: jquery

Como puedo agregar estas clases

```
.error textarea {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.error .counter {
  color: red;
}
```

al metodo addclass lo estoy intentando asi pero no me funciona

```
$("textarea").addClass("error textarea")

$("textarea").addClass("error counter")
```

Comment: Hola Oscar. Puedes hacer un [mcve] para probar tu codigo? Tambien, has hecho logs para ver que puede estar pasando ? Recuerda leer [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los selectores que estas usando, separados por un espacio, son para seleccionar elementos `textarea` y `counter` que estén *DENTRO* de otro elemento con clase `error`.

Si quieres seleccionar elementos que contengan ambas clases, elimina el espacio:

```
.error.textarea {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.error.counter {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: gracias hice lo que dijiste y funciono

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende claramente lo que quieres hacer pero si entendí bien podrías probar esto:

```
<div id="textarea">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    $('#textarea').addClass('error');
</script>
```

*No hay necesidad de agregarle textarea al addClass() ya que al seleccionar al padre este busca a su hijo y aplica los cambios.*

eso es lo que pediste que hiciera el CSS

```
.error textarea {...}
```

**espero te sirva.**